# Counting frequency of unique value in a shapefile column in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

My shapefile has a column named 'crop'. I have identified unique values of different crops like wheat lentil etc. Now, my goal is to get the frequency of each unique crop in that column. Means I am trying to get number of times a particular crop's point is recorded. My code in GEE is given below:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/GEOINFORMERS/TestAfghanistan_March2020_Comb");

var crop = table.aggregate_array('Crop'); //select one column from shapefile
var cropUniq = crop.distinct();           //select distict records
//var myList = ee.List(cropUniq);
print ('Unique Crops', cropUniq);                         // print unique items from that column

var getcount = function(string) {
  var i = cropUniq.get(0); i <= cropUniq.get(-1); i = i+1
  var crop = cropUniq.getInfo(i)
  var fil = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Crop', crop))
  return fil.size()
};

//print('getinfo', cropUniq.getInfo())
var count =  cropUniq.map(getcount);
print ('Crop-wise Count',count);
```

Maybe I am doing a silly mistake in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for `reduceColumns()`:

```
var output = table.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['Crop']);
print(output)
```

Let me know if it works for your dataset, as you didn't share the asset.

Comment: Thank you very much. this is exactly what I was looking for.